# Track the timing of click in notification in android

Tags: android, json, notifications, push-notification

I want to track the timing of the notification click so that i can post it into json to get the next notification. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: When you click on notification , if you are opening activity than just write new Date() or System.currentTimeMillis() as per your requirement

Comment: i have done it. see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233169/how-to-remove-notification-instantly-in-android   @Rstar

Comment: why are you making so complex logic

Comment: can you tell me how to do it simple?

Comment: Just do one thing onCreate of DashboardActivity.this just getTime

Comment: Will you post your OP here

Comment: see the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233169/how-to-remove-notification-instantly-in-android @Rstar